# Multisite stuck at 1MB for max file size

Tags: multisite, uploads

I have a Wordpress Multisite install on our FreeBSD development server. It seems to be stuck at 1MB.

I have the following settings in `php.ini`

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M  
post_max_size = 100M  
max_execution_time = 300
```

All the regular WordPress installs on the site have a max upload size of 100MB, as expected. Regardless of the values I put the multisite install is stuck at 1MB.

The setup:

- FreeBSD 8.1
- PHP 5.3.3
- Wordpress Multisite 3.2.1

After moving the site to another server on Rackspace, it has the same issues.

Any help on getting this limit raised would be appreciated. If I left any pertinent information out let me know and I'll provide what I can.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a [network admin settings page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Settings_Screen) with a Max upload file size field, make sure this is also set correctly.

Comment: Excellent! My first real foray into multisite, so some of the differences are taking a bit of getting used to.

Comment: The settings page is at `/wp-admin/network/settings.php`