# Can't upload files 1MB+

Tags: uploads, media, configuration, limit, audio

I can't upload files with more than 1MB, but i haven't change any configuration. I have a lot of files with more than 5MB uploaded before, but i don't know why now i can't... The error is "Failed to write file to disk."

In my media page says max file size is 100MB. Any idea how i can solve this?

I am newbie with WordPress, and never see this problem before... I read this topic [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/268435/wordpress-site-stuck-at-1mb-for-max-file-size) but this doesn't helped me, i installed [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-max-file-size/) plugin to try improve my limit, but this changed my limit to 0B.

Comment: Is there any chance you've hit a limit on your hosting account, i.e. you have run out of disk space or disk quota?

Comment: this article will surely help
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/

Comment: There also might be an upload file size limit enforced by the webhost.

Comment: Tips from your link @RaashidDin doesn't worked for me

Comment: How can i see limit from my host account? I don't know

Comment: Do you have shell access? Try `df -h`. If not it'll depend on who your host is.

Comment: Hey Matheus, this issue is a server-specific issue. You need to raise your PHP upload limit.

Comment: I will try to solve this in my host... Thanks for the patience guys :)

Answer (score 1):

First and most important step.  Check and make sure your hosting account has the available space.  Login to your hosting control panel and check how much disk space you have used.

Next verify your PHP settings are actually what you have tried to set them to (this will tell you the limits set in PHP):

Create a PHP file in your root WordPress directory:

`phpinfox823842832.php`

Inside that PHP file put:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Then browse to `http://yourdomain.com/phpinfox823842832.php`

You can review the PHP settings to verify the overrides you are using are actually being used.  After doing this, remove that file.

Review this site for more details on checking and setting upload limits in WordPress:
https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-maximum-upload-file-size/#

Next check your folder permissions, using FTP or your web hosting control panel, make sure that directories are set to 755:
https://www.hostpapa.com/knowledgebase/fix-upload-failed-write-file-disk-error-wordpress/

Have you tried uploading files via FTP to verify that you can actually upload to your hosting account?